# Line issue with table, how to center on multirow

Tags: tables, equations, align

I am trying to create a table, but some things are off. I am new to `LaTeX`, so even to get to this state was not easy.

[image]
The following image shows the adjustments I would like to do.
[image: to fix]

- The lines marked with cyan color are missing.
- The lines marked with red color are not supposed to be drawn.
- If possible the text within the blue boxes should be horizontally centered, and the also at the bottom of the cell.
- Also, would it be possible to have the equations within the green box be an align environment inside a multirow. (I need advice on what would be better for this particular part)

> I am resizing the table because it is overflowing the page, if there is another way of avoiding it, I am open to suggestions.

**Table was created with the following code:**

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{rrrrrl|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| }
            \hline
            \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{(a) Forma Algebraica}} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{(b) Forma Tabular}} \\ \hline

            \multicolumn{6}{c|}{} & \multirow{2}{3em}{\textbf{Var. basica}} & \multirow{2}{0.9em}{\textbf{Eq.}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Coeficiente}} & \multirow{2}{2em}{\textbf{Lado der.}} \\

            \multicolumn{6}{c|}{} & & & $Z$ & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ \\
            \hline
            $(0)$ & $Z$ & $-180x_1$ & $-90x_2$ & & $= 0$ & $Z$ & $(0)$ & $Z$ & $-180$ & $-90$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
            \hline
            $(1)$ & & $6x_1$ & $+ 8x_2$ & $+ x_3$ & $=48$ & $x_3$ & $(1)$ & $Z$ & $6$ & $8$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $48$ \\
            \hline
            $(2)$ & & $x_1$ & & $+ x_4$ & $= 6$ & $x_4$ & $(2)$ & $Z$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $6$ \\
            \hline
            $(3)$ & & & $x_2$ & $+ x_5$ & $= 4$ & $x_5$ & $(3)$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $4$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{Forma tabular.}
    \label{tab:simplex_tabular_0}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

- It is not entirely clear how what you mean with "would it be possible to have the equations within the green box be an align environment inside a multirow". This can be done on several ways:

  - with lines between math rows, see case A
  - us before but without lines between math rows, see case B
  - with use `aligned` environment of `amsmath`, see case C
- You have defined one column more than needed.
- Aligning of multirow cell can be nicely done by use of `makecell` package.
- I would not use `scalebox`. Rather reduce font size to `\small`

**Case A:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin={2.5cm,4cm},
            vmargin={3cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{array,  makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize\linespread{0.8}\selectfont}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
    \renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{} c *{4}{r@{\;}}l|*{8}{c|}c @{}}
    \hline
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{(a) Forma Algebraica}} 
    & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{(b) Forma Tabular}}    \\ 
    \hline

\multicolumn{6}{c|}{} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Var.\\ basica}} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\\Eq.}} 
            & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente}} 
                & \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Lado\\ der.}}  \\
    \cline{9-14}
\multicolumn{6}{c|}{} 
    &   &   & $Z$ & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ \\
    \hline
$(0)$ & $Z$ & $-180x_1$ & $-90x_2$ & & $= 0$ & $Z$ & $(0)$ & $Z$ & $-180$ & $-90$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \hline
$(1)$ & & $6x_1$ & $+ 8x_2$ & $+ x_3$ & $=48$ & $x_3$ & $(1)$ & $Z$ & $6$ & $8$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $48$ \\
    \hline
$(2)$ & & $x_1$ & & $+ x_4$ & $= 6$ & $x_4$ & $(2)$ & $Z$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $6$ \\
    \hline
$(3)$ & & & $x_2$ & $+ x_5$ & $= 4$ & $x_5$ & $(3)$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $4$ \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Forma tabular.}
\label{tab:simplex_tabular_0}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

- Another possibility is to use `tabularray` package.
- With it table is a bit nicer and code for table body simpler.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin={2.5cm,4cm},
            vmargin={3cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vline{7-Y},
             colsep   = 4pt,
             colspec  = {@{}  Q[c,mode=math] 
                              Q[c,mode=math, rightsep=1pt]
                         *{3}{Q[r,mode=math, colsep=1pt]}
                         *{4}{Q[c,mode=math]}
                         *{5}{X[c,mode=math]} 
                              c @{}},
             row{1,2} = {mode=text, font=\bfseries}
             }
\SetCell[c=6]{c}    (a) Forma Algebraica
    &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=9]{c}    (b) Forma Tabular   
                            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
\SetCell[c=6, r=2]{c}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{f}  {Var.\\ basica} 
                            &   \SetCell[r=2]{f}    Eq.
                                &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}    Coeficiente
                                    &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{f}  {Lado\\ der.}  \\
    &   &           &           &       &       &       &       & Z & x_1   & x_2   & x_3   & x_4   & x_5   &       \\
(0) & Z & -180x_1   & -90x_2    &       & = 0   & Z     & (0)   & Z & -180  & -90   & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     \\
(1) &   & 6x_1      & + 8x_2    & + x_3 & =48   & x_3   & (1)   & Z & 6     & 8     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 48    \\
(2) &   & x_1       &           & + x_4 & = 6   & x_4   & (2)   & Z & 1     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0     & 6     \\
(3) &   &           & x_2       & + x_5 & = 4   & x_5   & (3)   & 0 & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 4     \\
\end{tblr}

\caption{Forma tabular.}
\label{tab:simplex_tabular_0}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Case B:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin={2.5cm,4cm},
            vmargin={3cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2-4,Z}, vline{2,7-Y}={1-Z}{solid},
             hline{2,5-Z} = {1,7-Z}{solid},
             colsep   = 4pt,
             colspec  = {@{}  Q[c,mode=math]
                              Q[r,mode=math,rightsep=1pt]
                         *{3}{Q[r,mode=math,colsep=1pt]}
                              Q[l,mode=math]
                         *{3}{Q[c,mode=math]}
                         *{5}{X[c,mode=math]}
                              c @{}},
             row{1,2} = {mode=text, font=\bfseries}
             }
\SetCell[c=6]{h}    (a) Forma Algebraica
    &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=9]{c}    (b) Forma Tabular
                            &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &       \\
\SetCell[c=6, r=2]{c}
    &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{f}  {Var.\\ basica}
                            &   \SetCell[r=2]{f}    Eq.
                                &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}    Coeficiente
                                                &       &       &   &       &       &          \SetCell[r=2]{f}  {Lado\\ der.}  \\
    &               &       &   &       &       &       &       & Z & x_1   & x_2   & x_3   & x_4   & x_5   &       \\
(0) & Z & -180x_1   & -90x_2    &       & = 0   & Z     & (0)   & Z & -180  & -90   & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     \\
(1) &   & 6x_1      & + 8x_2    & + x_3 & =48   & x_3   & (1)   & Z & 6     & 8     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 48    \\
(2) &   & x_1       &           & + x_4 & = 6   & x_4   & (2)   & Z & 1     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0     & 6     \\
(3) &   &           & x_2       & + x_5 & = 4   & x_5   & (3)   & 0 & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 4     \\
\end{tblr}

\caption{Forma tabular.}
\label{tab:simplex_tabular_0}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Case C:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin={2.5cm,4cm},
            vmargin={3cm,2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \small
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2-4,Z}, vline{3-Y}={1-Z}{solid},
             hline{5-Z} = {3-Z}{solid},
             colsep   = 4pt,
             colspec  = {@{}
                         *{7}{Q[c,mode=math]}
                         *{4}{X[c,mode=math]}
                                @{}},
             row{1,2} = {mode=text, font=\bfseries}
             }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    (a) Forma Algebraica
    &                       &   \SetCell[c=9]{c}    (b) Forma Tabular
                                    &       &   &       &       &       &       &       &       \\
\SetCell[c=2,r=2]{c}
    &                       &   \SetCell[r=2]{f}  {Var.\\ basica}
                                &   \SetCell[r=2]{f}    Eq.
                                        &   \SetCell[c=6]{c}    Coeficiente
                                                    &       &       &       &       &       &   \SetCell[r=2]{f}  {Lado\\ der.}  \\
    &                           &       &       & Z & x_1   & x_2   & x_3   & x_4   & x_5   &       \\
(0) & \SetCell[r=4]{c}
    \begin{aligned}
    Z - 180x_1 - 90x_2  & =  0\\
    6x_1 + 8x_2 + x_3   & = 48\\
     x_1 + x_4          & =  6\\
    x_2 + x_5           & =  4\\
    \end{aligned}               & Z     & (0)   & Z & -180  & -90   & 0     & 0     & 0     & 0     \\
(1) &                           & x_3   & (1)   & Z & 6     & 8     & 1     & 0     & 0     & 48    \\
(2) &                           & x_4   & (2)   & Z & 1     & 0     & 0     & 1     & 0     & 6     \\
(3) &                           & x_5   & (3)   & 0 & 0     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 1     & 4     \\
\end{tblr}

\caption{Forma tabular.}
\label{tab:simplex_tabular_0}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it really helped and gave me some insight on the inner workings of the tabular environment.
But am unable to fully understand this line
```\begin{tabular}{@{} c *{4}{r@{\;}}l|*{8}{c|}c @{}}```

@Zarko Could you please explain how to use the * and @ symbols?

Comment: @OppositeDragon, just type asterix, for @ try `\@`,  however for more precise answer I should see context of their use. So far is not clear what problem you have with those symbols.

Comment: I have no problem with them, I just don't fully understand how they work, that's all.

Comment: @OppositeDragon, >I suggest you to read some introductory text about LaTeX. For example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{rrrrrl|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}[hlines]
\RowStyle[bold,nb-rows=2]{}
\Block{1-6}{(a) Forma Algebraica} &&&&&& \Block{1-9}{(b) Forma Tabular} \\ 
\Block[t]{2-6}{} &&&&&& \Block[t]{2-1}{Var.\\ basica} & \Block[t]{2-1}{\textbf{Eq.}} & \Block{1-6}{Coeficiente} &&&&&& \Block{2-1}{Lado\\ der.} \\
& & & &&&&& $Z$ & $x_1$ & $x_2$ & $x_3$ & $x_4$ & $x_5$ \\
$(0)$ & $Z$ & $-180x_1$ & $-90x_2$ & & $= 0$ & $Z$ & $(0)$ & $Z$ & $-180$ & $-90$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
$(1)$ & & $6x_1$ & $+ 8x_2$ & $+ x_3$ & $=48$ & $x_3$ & $(1)$ & $Z$ & $6$ & $8$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $48$ \\
$(2)$ & & $x_1$ & & $+ x_4$ & $= 6$ & $x_4$ & $(2)$ & $Z$ & $1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $6$ \\
$(3)$ & & & $x_2$ & $+ x_5$ & $= 4$ & $x_5$ & $(3)$ & $0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $4$ \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Forma tabular.}
\label{tab:simplex_tabular_0}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]