# Increase padding of cell, only when needed. (\dfrac)

Tags: tables

I have been searching for a solution, but most modify all rows, or use a different packages. I would like to only add padding where the numbers are touching the horizontal lines, without modifying the other rows.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
    % \renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}

    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{2.5em}{\textbf{Var. basica}}
              & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{ Eq.}}
              & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente}}
              & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Lado der.}}                                                                                              \\
        \cline{3-8}
              &                                           &
        $Z$   & $x_1$                                     & $x_2$ & $x_3$  & $x_4$ & $x_5$                                                       \\
        \hline
        $Z$   & $(0)$                                     & $1$   & $-180$ & $-90$ & $0$   & $0$ & $0$ & $0$                                     \\
        \hline
        $x_3$ & $(1)$                                     & $0$   & $6$    & $8$   & $1$   & $0$ & $0$ & $48 \to \dfrac{48}{ 6} = 8 $            \\
        \hline
        $x_4$ & $(2)$                                     & $0$   & $1$    & $0$   & $0$   & $1$ & $0$ & $6 \to \dfrac{6}{1} = 6 \leftarrow min$ \\
        \hline
        $x_5$ & $(3)$                                     & $0$   & $0$    & $1$   & $1$   & $1$ & $1$ & $4$                                     \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Aplicacion de la prueba de proporcion minima}
    \label{tab:simplex_tabular_1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with issues]

Comment: why `\dfrac` not `\frac`? also `min` should be`\mathrm{min}` but `\rule[xxx]{0pt}{yyy}` will allow you to force any amount of space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Could you please elaborate on that? do you mean \rule.. instead of \hline?

Comment: If you would use solutions from case B and C (which use `tabularray` package for writing of tables) in my answer to your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/686961/line-issue-with-table-how-to-center-on-multirow), than you would have desired behaviours of rows.

Comment: @Zarko, I have a pretty long document, with dozens of tables only using tabular, I think last time I tried using other table packages, I got some conflicts, that is why I have been sticking to tabular only. Thanks for mentioning it though.

Comment: Well, then struggle with your problems. Using `tabularray` along other table doesn't make any conflict with other tables' packages. You have problems with some other consistency in your document. Since it is not known, to me I can't advice how to manage with them.

Answer (score 7):

I would use `\frac` not `\dfrac` but you can force space by adding a strut

[image]

from

```
$x_3$ & $(1)$   & $0$  & $6$  & $8$ & $1$  & $0$ & $0$ 
              & \rule[-12pt]{1pt}{30pt}$48 \to \dfrac{48}{ 6} = 8 $ \\
```

adjust the lengths to your requirements.  The `{1pt}` width is just for
easy debugging, change to `{0pt}` at the end so it is invisible.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use strategically placed `\mathstrut` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c}
  \hline \frac{48}{6}\\ \hline
\end{array}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\begin{array}{c}
  \hline \frac{48^{\mathstrut}}{6_{\mathstrut}}\\ \hline
\end{array}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{array}{c}
  \hline \dfrac{48}{6}\\ \hline
\end{array}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\begin{array}{c}
  \hline \dfrac{48^{\mathstrut}}{6_{\mathstrut}}\\ \hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, I use `\addstackgap[gapsize]{}` from the `stackengine` package.  I have set `\stackMath` so that the argument is evaluated in math mode.  Just for demonstration, I add 2pt of buffer above and below `48/6` and 4pt of buffer to `6/1`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
    % \renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}

    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{2.7em}{\textbf{Var. basica}}
              & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{ Eq.}}
              & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente}}
              & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Lado der.}}                                                                                              \\
        \cline{3-8}
              &                                           &
        $Z$   & $x_1$                                     & $x_2$ & $x_3$  & $x_4$ & $x_5$                                                       \\
        \hline
        $Z$   & $(0)$                                     & $1$   & $-180$ & $-90$ & $0$   & $0$ & $0$ & $0$                                     \\
        \hline
        $x_3$ & $(1)$                                     & $0$   & $6$    & $8$   & $1$   & $0$ & $0$ & $48 \to \addstackgap[2pt]{\dfrac{48}{ 6}} = 8 $            \\
        \hline
        $x_4$ & $(2)$                                     & $0$   & $1$    & $0$   & $0$   & $1$ & $0$ & $6 \to \addstackgap[4pt]{\dfrac{6}{1}} = 6 \leftarrow min$ \\
        \hline
        $x_5$ & $(3)$                                     & $0$   & $0$    & $1$   & $1$   & $1$ & $1$ & $4$                                     \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Aplicacion de la prueba de proporcion minima}
    \label{tab:simplex_tabular_1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

By replacing the environment `{tabular}` by an environment `{NiceTabular}` of the package `nicematrix` with the key `cell-space-limits=2pt`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,left=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \small
    % \renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}

    \begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|l}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{2.5em}{\textbf{Var. basica}}
              & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{ Eq.}}
              & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{Coeficiente}}
              & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Lado der.}}                                                                                              \\
        \cline{3-8}
              &                                           &
        $Z$   & $x_1$                                     & $x_2$ & $x_3$  & $x_4$ & $x_5$                                                       \\
        \hline
        $Z$   & $(0)$                                     & $1$   & $-180$ & $-90$ & $0$   & $0$ & $0$ & $0$                                     \\
        \hline
        $x_3$ & $(1)$                                     & $0$   & $6$    & $8$   & $1$   & $0$ & $0$ & $48 \to \dfrac{48}{ 6} = 8 $            \\
        \hline
        $x_4$ & $(2)$                                     & $0$   & $1$    & $0$   & $0$   & $1$ & $0$ & $6 \to \dfrac{6}{1} = 6 \leftarrow min$ \\
        \hline
        $x_5$ & $(3)$                                     & $0$   & $0$    & $1$   & $1$   & $1$ & $1$ & $4$                                     \\
        \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \caption{Aplicacion de la prueba de proporcion minima}
    \label{tab:simplex_tabular_1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]